# string split with conditions

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm trying to create automatic folder creation through using the files; that are going inside; to be the name of the folder. This is a issue for me where some of the file names have multiple special characters, but I only need to remove a selected string, for example:

filename: "Common - check - 01[1080p].mp4", "Directory_test File - 01.txt"

I want the file to keep the first "-", but remove everything where it starts at the " - 01[1080p].mp4" or " - 01.txt".

```
 public bool creator(string mainFolder, string Folder)
    {
        try
        {
            //split to get the folder name, but only remove part of the text
            string[] split = Folder.Split('-');
            //making file path for folder
            string folderpath = Path.Combine(mainFolder, split[0]);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(mainFolder, Folder);
            // moving or/and creating folders and files
            if (!check(folderpath))
            {
                //creating creating folder
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
                //moving file
                File.Move(filePath, folderpath);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //moving file
                File.Move(filePath, folderpath);
                return true;
            }        
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first sentence is pretty unclear, but it seems you're on the right path. If I understand from your examples, you should split by hyphen (-) and name the folder using all but the last segment in the split.

Comment: Also, you don't really need the `check(folderpath)`, since `CreateDirectory` will only create a directory if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: You want to split `Common - check - 01[1080p].mp4` and `Directory_test File - 01.txt` on the last hyphen?

Comment: Wait, is `Folder` a directory or a file name? It appears in code to be a file name, but the name `Folder` is very confusing.

Comment: @The Fourth Bird, yes I'm trying to but don't want to take the first one away.

Comment: @Rufus L Sorry that is my mistake I copied incorrect. I've update the snippet in the description to correct variable name `public bool creator(string mainFolder, string Folder)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two simple options:

```
string f = "Common - check - 01[1080p].mp4";
// If you need the individual parts...
string[] parts = f.Split('-');
string newName = string.Join("-", parts.Take(parts.Length - 1));
Console.WriteLine(newName);

// If you don't...
newName = f.Substring(0, f.LastIndexOf('-'));
Console.WriteLine(newName);
```

Although you probably want to call `.Trim()` on the result of either to avoid a trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to organize files in a directory by creating folders for them based on the file name, and are having trouble finding the last instance of the `-` character to create the folder name.

One easy way to do this would be to use the `LastIndexOf` method, which will return the index of the last instance of the string `"-"`, or `-1` if it isn't found.

I think there's also some other optimizations you could use here, where you can just take in the main folder name and then look through all the files at once (this may not be exactly what you want, but it's something I've used in the past). So you only need to take in the `mainFolder` path, and then the method can do the rest. Also, you can call `CreateDirectory` safely even if the directory already exists (it will just not do anything in that case).

Here's an example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Moves all files in mainFolder to a subfolder based on the file's name
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mainFolder">The root folder to scan for files</param>
/// <returns>true if the operation was successful</returns>
public static bool OrganizeFiles(string mainFolder)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(mainFolder)) 
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(nameof(mainFolder));

    try
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(mainFolder))
        {
            var subFolderName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            var lastHyphen = subFolderName.LastIndexOf("-");

            if (lastHyphen > -1)
            {
                subFolderName = subFolderName.Substring(0, lastHyphen);
            }

            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(mainFolder, subFolderName));

            File.Move(file, subFolderName);
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```